# Angular upgrade from 14 to 15 causing angular material date range mat label text overflow

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-upgrade

I have a demo application in angular, where we have a date range picker with mat label. Adding long text to mat label is geting text overflow. Adding overflow hidden doesn't work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/muzdwo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html,package.json

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Angular on this version. The bug is presented [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26337). To have a fix for the problem just add into **styles.scss**:

```
.mat-mdc-floating-label {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When you click the input box on the date range, it has enough room to display the full text but still puts .... at the end

Comment: you can click in the example in here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/muzdwo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss